# Joda DateTimeFormatter Invalid format

Tags: java, jodatime

I am getting the above error, but to me everything seems to be correct.

What I am doing wrong?

```
DateTimeFormatter simpleDateFormatInput= DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

DateTime datetime = simpleDateFormatInput.parseDateTime(pubDate);
```

Where pubDate is `Sat, 30 Jan 2016 12:23:53 +0100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The day and/or month from your input String may not match those from your default `Locale`. Try

```
DateTimeFormatter simpleDateFormatInput = 
   DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").withLocale(Locale.US);
```